# Rewrite file in Tomcat, default Lucee instance, Configure SES for FW/1

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, lucee

I run Coldfusion on my IIS box, but I have an instance of Lucee running for testing.  I have it running as http://127.0.0.1:8888  I've replaced the files in the default root (tomcat/webapps/root/*)to be my application.  The main page loads, but whenever I navigate to a subdirectory (this app used to be on IIS/Lucee) I get a 404.  I need to configure the rewrite rules, but the documentation for Tomcat 8 is rather sparse on examples, particularly with what I'm trying to do.

I have the default name of 'action' still set in Framework 1 (FW/1).  So, basically what I'm trying to do is anytime some requests:
host:8888/main/default it translates that request to host:8888/index.cfm?action=main.default

Thank you to all who take the time!

Comment: What rewrite method are you currently using? The rewrite valve? https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html

Comment: Yes, the rewrite valve.